# Node.js child processes on Heroku with single Dyno

Tags: node.js, heroku

Pardon my ignorance, I'm currently learning how to use Node coming from a PHP background where I really had no interaction with Apache or server management. I'm using Heroku to host my Node projects, pushed straight from the Cloud9 IDE.

From what I've read, a Heroku dyno is a single web process, buying additional dynos will allow you to deal with more traffic coming in because by increasing dynos you increase the size of the amount of requests that you can deal with at any one time.

I know the Node is a single-threaded system that deals with requests one by one, allowing you to spawn child processes for anything that may take some time to deal with (like database requests, processing files etc).

So what happens in Heroku if I spawn a child process with a single dyno? Does this not need another dyno to work on? Surely if Node is running a single process and I only have one process available in my single dyno any extra processes are going to have to be handled by that one too?

Or do I have this all wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't have to launch separate node processes to make database requests and file processing happen asynchronously... not having to do so is the benefit of nodejs.  If you're spawning a non-deterministic number of worker "threads/processes" you are absolutely using NodeJS incorrectly.  And with that answer, I believe you should be able to answer your own question.  If you would like more detail, let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your response, Chris. I might not have explained myself properly - my knowledge of Node at the moment doesn't stretch too far outside of that detailed in the Node Beginner book, in which an example uses `var exec = require("child_process").exec;` and then later uses the `exec` function in performing an expensive shell operation to demonstrate non-blocking code. So, as I understand, in this example the shell operation is being deferred to another process so that the main process can continue to take new requests and later receive a callback to display the initial request's response.

Comment: I submitted my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding of exec is roughly correct, my concern is that you are using it when you do not need to do so... In your question you only mention I/O types of oeprations, which node handles very efficiently within it's single threaded event model of doing things. Despite being single threaded, the event model allows code to run without blocking the main event loop(unless you're doing VERY CPU intensive operations..., of which Database requests, and file processing are not included) That being said, you should not need to launch an additional dyno to do what you want.

Think of a dyno as a single processor computer. Whatever you can do on a machine that has a single processor you can do on your dyno, with no extra charges or created dynos. Though, a dyno does have considerably less memory than a single core processor computer could take advantage of. So, any subprocesses you wish to spawn do not need another dyno to run on. Every master process you wish to run, will need its own dyno.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('An amount of data that will take 1 second to send');//This will not block the event loop
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    while(true) {
         break after 1 second; //this will block the event loop for 1 second
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Consider the two servers in the code above.  Both servers have roughly one second of work to do.  The first example can service thousands of requests per second, the second example only 1.  Sending data, database requests, server requests, file IO, etc... all would behave as the first example... very few things in Node behave like the second example.  If you have something that fits under the second example, you are likely better off picking a different language, than trying to force node to work for a use case it is very poorly designed for.

Comment: Oh, ok. So it seems I was mistaking single process with single thread..? Do you know if there is a limit to the amount of processes I can run on one dyno?

Comment: I would like to strongly discourage you from launching an abundance of processes.  If you believe that your node process requires the launching of more than 1 or 2 workers for a processor, you are likely not using node correctly, or your use case would be better suited for a different programming language.  I will write a little demo code for you.  That being said, the number is likely limited only by whatever operating system heroku is using, not on any limitations they wish to place upon you.

Comment: Thus your true limitation, is likely RAM.  Dynos can support 512MB of ram(last I checked, which was a while ago).  When you fork a process, the memory from that process comes with you, copied over into it's own environment.  So assuming a 100MB process, you could spawn 5 such processes.  (The math here isn't quite exact, this is just an overview, benchmarking might be in order)

Comment: Thanks very much for the code example. So, let's say that the first server is going to take some data and use that to do a curl-like request to another site that is slow, taking 3 seconds to respond, and then return the data from that site. Would this be blocking, or does Node handle this in a non-blocking way automatically?

Comment: Anytime you see in a node function take a parameter for a callback function, this is a function that will not block the event loop, and will behave as the first example.  In general if your using Node Library functions, you don't have to worry about blocking the event loop, and should treat that bit of code as if it is running on it's own thread(this isn't necessarily how it actually works, but if you think of it this way it is a little easier to wrap your head around, than trying to understand what V8 is really doing with your code)